# create object in hibernate select

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have 2 classes:

```
class A {
B b;

public A() {}
public A(B b) { setB(b); }
...
}

class B {
int id;
public B(int id) { setId(id); }
}
```

in hql I want to select like this:

```
select new A( new B(a.b.id) ) from A a
```

but I got error

> org.hibernate.hql.PARSER - line 1:48: unexpected token: ,

Is it possible to create object in parameter, or select just field and create it inside constructor?

Comment: What exactly do you want? Why do you need to use `new` here, can't you just do `SELECT a ...`?

Comment: in this class is more fields and I don't want to select them.

Comment: witch "select new A(a.b.id) from A a" hibernate will generate select just for that field and not for other eager fields. What I want is to get object instead of int value. But in B also is some eager fields, that I don't need, therefore I don't want to get full B object.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether I exactly understood what you want to achieve. But you can create a HQL query (with projection) to only query for the columns you're intereset in, like:

```
select a.whatever, b.id from A a join a.b b
```

Afterwards you provide an implementation for the interface [ResultTransformer](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/transform/ResultTransformer.html) and set it to your `query` object with `query.setResultTransformer(yourTransformer)`

Your implementation of the result transformer is responsible for creating instances for `A` and `B`

Comment: this query just return list of whatever and id. I need object A list, but if A is big and have lot relation to other objects, selecting this A can take some times. Some times I just need list of A with only few fields from only few related objects. I can do that with "select new A(a.whatever, a.b) from A", but than it will select full B object, and I need only id from it, therefore best query would by "select new A(a.whatever, new B(a.b.id) from A" but hibernate not allow that. therefor I need create other classes with only field I need.

Answer (score 1):

maybe look into writing your own function to build your queries and use of the StrinBuilder class - use hql.append instead of writing out the query !!!

import org.hibernate.Hibernate;
import org.hibernate.search.FullTextQuery;
import org.hibernate.search.FullTextSession;
import org.hibernate.search.Search;

not sure if it helps, otherwise go and check out cyclos web app - it includes lots of queries and according java files. Its open source and uses comprhensive hibernate

regards